# How can I add conditions to simplify the result?

Tags: functions, matrix, simplifying-expressions, conditional

Here k is an integer number. How can I simplify the result by adding conditions like k is odd or even?

Also why are the 0^k terms not simplified to 0?

```
A = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, -2}};
MatrixFunction[#^k &, A] // FullSimplify // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Try `Simplify[A^k, {Element[k, PositiveIntegers] }]`

Comment: `MatrixFunction[#^k &, A] // 
  FullSimplify[#, k > 0 && Mod[k, 2] == 0] & // MatrixForm`?

Comment: @kglr that Mod is neat

Comment: @kglr  Why the restriction `Mod[k,2]`? `A^1` , `A^3`,...is allowed,  I think.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, `Mod[k, 2] == 0`  is to add the assumption/condition that `k` is even. For simplification under the assumption that  `k` is odd, we need ``Mod[k, 2] ==1`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, I overread this restriction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get some simplification by assuming k>0

```
A = {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, -2}};
Simplify[MatrixFunction[#^k &, A], Assumptions -> k > 0] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]